# Is there a normalizer for undergrad grades in institutions across the world?

Tags: undergraduate, grades

I could swear I once saw somewhere in under duke.edu a pdf that lists undergrad institutions across the world with a way to interpret their grades qualitatively. I can't find it anymore. Is there any other document that tells for various institutions how to interpret their grades?

Comment: No, of course not.  There isn't even a normalizer for undergraduate grades between different instructors of the same course in the same department at the same university.

Comment: @JeffE I'm sure there is a counter-example to that claim.

Comment: Not true. I definitely saw a document that does such normalization, I just can't find it anywhere.

Comment: @JeffE: As a counterexample to your claim, see myedu.com.

Comment: @BenCrowell If there's a grade normalizer there, I can't find it, and I wouldn't trust its accuracy.  See http://easy-a.net/about/ for **actual data** about grade distributions at my university over a five year period, derived from FOIA requests.  In some of the larger courses, average grades for the same course vary by more than a letter grade between sections, depending on the instructor.